# GitHub pages leads to 404 error for URLs with forward slash

Tags: github-pages

I was able to deploy a single page site (index.html + vanilla JavaScript) with custom URL on GitHub pages but my URLs with forward slash `/` display `404 - File not found`.

`https://example.org` - works as expected and my site gets displayed.

`https://example.org/home` - here `/home` results in `404`.

After running a few tests I found copying `index.html` into a folder `docs/home/index.html` resolves this but this is going to be difficult to maintain for many nested URLs. I will have to create multiple folders for each URL.

This can also be fixed using `#` instead of `/` so my url becomes `https://example.org#home` but this might not be good for search engines.

Another option is that I prefix `/?/` for all urls which works but seems a bit hacky

- `https://example.org/?/home`
- `https://example.org/?/home/page1`
- `https://example.org/?/home/page1/page2`

Another option that I haven't tried is have a `404.html` with the same content as `index.html` but this is not a proper use of `404`.

I really don't know how to fix this. How do I make my URLs with forward slash `/` work GitHub pages?